# How can I make a PNG image (imported as "Image as plane") transparent on back side?

Tags: image, transparency

I have a PNG image that I would like to be transparent/invisible from the back.
but still retain alpha transparency of the background from the front.
I am trying to see through this image but still have it reflect in a shiny metal surface.
I was able to make it invisible from the back by adding a backfacing output of a geometry node  into the alpha of the BSDF, but this stops the background transparency on the front of the image.
Is it possible  ?
[image]

Comment: Instead of connecting the _Backfacing_ to the Alpha, use a MIx Shader, mixing your Principled BSDF with a Transparent BSDF using the _Backfacing_ as a mix factor. If you're using eevee, don't forget to change the blend mode to something other than _Opaque_.

Comment: OK thanks, I will try that.

Comment: Also I just tried mixing the Alpha channels using a multiply maths node and this worked perfectly too.  It is resolved really.